# Main user for app - best implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, uitabbarcontroller

I'm creating an app, it is looks like Twitter app, UITabBarController + UINavigationController.

In my app i need to have one main user (e.g. **YOU**) and other users, **YOU** and users sharing same structure i.e. class.

With bunch of ordinary users i don't see a problem - you creating user object, using it, ARC doing its job.

My question is: what is best way to save **YOUrs** data, access or pass it between tabs(and tabs can be selected in no particular order).

I already read many q&a about this topic, and I can use:

1. global var;
2. class method (+);
3. singleton;
4. NSUserDefaults;

but, i don't think i really know right and **BEST** answer.

**Edit:**
Sorry if i wrote unclear, i'll try to explain better. 
When you start app, you need to login, after login you can talk to other users, make tasks for them etc.
There is really **one user** i want to store data for, because when i switch between tabs i need to know my id and other things. But other users i talk to is actually the same in terms of class design. They all need to have name, avatar, email, etc.

Comment: I think your question is not clear. You are talking about many users using the app, which has nothing to do with passing information between tabs... and also you're talking about 'saving' data... your question doesn't make any sense to me. Could you explain better what you want to do?

Comment: I updated question, please review it once again.

Comment: it isn't clear at all im afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still a little bit vague, because it's not clear if you're asking about saving data, or passing information from one view (tab) to another. But still I think I get what you're trying to do.

First let me clarify about your proposals, because some of these are totally unrelated one another:

1. **global var**; A global variable is a variable that you can access just from any part of your code, from any class, any method. This is highly discouraged in object oriented programming, and I would consider it a bad practice (unless you know what you're doing)
2. **class method (+)**; A class method is just a method that doesn't reference a particular instance of the class.
3. **singleton**; A singleton is a class that allows one and only one instance of itself. There are several ways of implementing them, and all have the same principle. The class methods (mentioned before) are commonly used with singletons to manage them.
4. **NSUserDefaults**; This is probably the most unrelated in the list. This is a class that is provided to save information persistently. For example you can store a list of recently used emoticons in the chat.

Designing the logic of your app is up to you. But one example is, let's say, with a ChatSystem object.

```
@interface ChatSystem...
{
     User *you;
     NSArray *otherUsers;
}
```

If you design your chatsystem object like this, you don't need any singletons, because YOU is always referenced by the same variable. All the other users are store in the array `otherUsers`.
You can pass the ChatSytem object across views (or tabs) and you'll always know which one is YOU because you reference it as

```
myChatSystem.you
```

As I said before, your question is vague, but I hope this helps you.

EDIT:
If there's only one logged-in user (YOU) you can manage it with a singleton. There are hundreds of examples of singletons out there, so grab any of these. So to access the YOU user just invoke use the singleton instance. In the above example it would be something like.

```
User *you; // Declared locally or in your class definition
you = [User singletonLoggedInUserInstance]; // get the logged In user
if (you)  // if user is valid, meaning there IS a logged in user
{
    //... do something, initiate chat conversation....
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't want to use a singleton, just the declare the user object as a property of your views, tabs or controllers that will do something with that object (or user). For example if object A creates the user, and object B wants do do something with that user you do something like this:

```
@interface TabA
@property.... User *user;
@property ... TabB *tabB;
@end

- (void)passUserToTabB
{
    self.tabB.user = self.user; //... pass user to Tab B
}


@interface TabB
@property.... User *user;
@end
```

Comment: I can not see any answer.. maybe some quoted docs but nothing else

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was down-voted by the question's owner.

Comment: I do not down-voted anyone. Merlevede, I like your example ChatSystem, I think it something that i need, i really don't thought about that, I'm new to objC. But now i want to ask about best practice to pass ChatSystem object between tabs (keeping in mind, that tabs can be switched in any order).

Comment: See the edited answer at the end

Comment: Thank you! I think it's best solution, and it feels like true to objC. I'll do it tomorrow.